# g-forces entering and leaving atmospheres, how would they vary from one body to another?

Tags: launch, crewed-spaceflight, reentry, atmosphere, g-force

I was wondering how launching from and returning into atmospheres of other bodies such as Mars, Venus, Titan, etc. would differ from Earth's.

Specifically, I am wondering how many g's would be experienced by the crew.

Is there likely to be large differences, or would missions be designed differently to produce accelerations on the crew similar to what modern Earth launches and reentries do?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? All planets have differing gases and different pressures. The only unique thing about Earth's atmosphere is that it is currently ideal for humans and other terrestrial life to survive.

Comment: Questions are usually required to be somewhat specific (this is not a forum). Can you clarify what you are looking for? And what differences you are already aware of?

Comment: I am wondering about the differences in the amount of g's felt by the crew when entering or leaving earth's atmosphere in comparison to another planet like Mars or Venus.

Comment: @aitia Now *that's* much more answerable. You should edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: The relationship is very indirect, at best, and distant enough to make me wonder if there is some misconception behind the question...it's much more a matter of vehicle design than of the atmosphere.

Comment: Perhaps I should change my question to ask how many g's result from entering and leaving the earth's atmosphere?

Comment: *This is a great question!* I've added a few "space words" to it to address the comments above. Does it still look okay?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you!